# How to disable initializing of graphics window of Python Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

everyone!

I want to implement the **Turtle** into my application just for the purpose of coordinate generation. The problem is that I need to get the coordinates of turtle move (etc.) **without any "pop-up window" containing the graphics** or even worse animation. **Is it possible somehow to disable initialization of turtle graphics?**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have solved the situation by using: speed(0); turtle.tracer(False); **turtle.bye()**. The graphics window is intialized but suddenly closed.